# 500 error while using htaccess in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cpanel

i have project in localhost , i apply the rewrite simple rule , it's work fine in localhost .when i upload in cpanel .Rewrite url (htaccess) work only for one page but not for others . means its give me 500 internal error. i convert Profile.php to domain.com/profile and  about-us.php to domain.com/about-us but it give me 500 error

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On                                        
RewriteEngine on                                                  
RewriteRule ^profile$ Profile.php [NC,L]                          
RewriteRule ^profile-setting$ User-Profile.php [NC,L]             
RewriteRule ^checkout$ checkout.php [NC,L]                        
RewriteRule ^summer-store$ product.php [NC,L]
```

only last product.php page work in both localhost and cpanel , but other only work on localhost not in cpanel(500 error) .Where is the Problem Exist.Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by `i convert Profile.php to domain.com/profile`? Did you change the file name or just the references to the page(s)? You are getting an apache error or PHP error?

Comment: like domain.com/Profile.php page exist on my server i want to convert   domain.com/profile    for this i apply that rule RewriteRule ^profile$ Profile.php [NC,L]     it give "  is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 "

Comment: charis85 can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access of the server where the website is hosted , just login to the server with root user and check the logs at path /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log while browsing the pages that have issues. The error log will show you whats happening and then you can apply the fixes accordingly.